# Google Sheets script Filter copy and paste with format

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am looking for help to create a filter on a Google Sheets Script.
I want the following:

- I have a database Schedule which has table with information that I want to filter
- Once the database A is updated I want to filter Colum b row 8 and only take the cells that have information and are filled with words, numbers, etc.
- After that I want to copy the data filtered and paste on a new Sheet Data “Foreman on specific columns
- Also I want to copy and paste the format such as color, size, etc.
- I have the following code which it does the partial job but I cannot figure it out to only get the specific data needed

```
function Foreman(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var scheduleCCC_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule");
  var Foreman_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foreman");
  var pasteforemans = Foreman_sheet.getRange(8,2);
  var originalData = scheduleCCC_sheet.getRange(9,2,scheduleCCC_sheet.getLastRow()1,11).getValues();
  var filter1 ="";
  Foreman_sheet.getRange(8,2,Foreman_sheet.getLastRow(),11).clearContent().clearFormat();
  var data = originalData.filter(filterlogic);

  Foreman_sheet.getRange(9,2,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}

var filterlogic = function(item){
  if(item[1] == ""){
    return false;
  }else {
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a sample of the data assigned to `originalData` and the expected result  from it. You could also add a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view. By the other hand the code doesn't copy/paste format if you want to focus this question on the filtering it's fine, but then you should remove the format part by the other hand if you want to keep it, you should know that besides grabbing the values with `getValues` you should grab the cell format or instead of grabbing each part you should use `copyTo`